# Qt и лицензирование

Tags: qt, лицензирование

Кто-нибудь может простым языком объяснить, чем отличаются лицензии **Qt**?

1) Можно ли использовать **Qt** для разработки продуктов, которые собираешься продавать?

2) Если ты разрабатываешь на **Qt** вещь, которая предназначена для свободного (и бесплатного) использования, например, для работы с графиками, моделями и пр., и если помимо **Qt** все остальные используемые составляющие являются свободными, то каковы ограничения в этом случае и есть ли они?

Comment: https://habr.com/post/331166/ может прояснит часть вопросов. а может и запутает

Comment: Пытался понять, что там написано, но не смог.

Answer (score 0):

> Коммерческая лицензия хранит ваш собственный код, где вы можете
>   контролировать и монетизировать разработку, использование и
>   распространение своего конечного продукта.
>
> Конфиденциальность приложений со статической и динамической связью
>   библиотек Qt.   Нет необходимости предоставлять копию лицензии или
>   явно признавать использование Qt.
>   Нет необходимости делать копию
>   вашего исходного кода Qt для клиентов. 
> Полные права на исправления
>   исходного кода Qt. Может создавать «закрытые» потребительские
>   устройства. Принудительное управление цифровыми правами.
>   Принудительные патенты на программное обеспечение.

[Исходник(англ)](https://www1.qt.io/buy-product/?utm_campaign=Buy%20Qt%202018&utm_source=ppc&utm_medium=search%20ad&utm_term=marketing&gclid=CjwKCAjwhqXbBRAREiwAucoo-9EOuBJ2SvlqwgFjVwLBSuv-x5vhOrmVEbgAWeOUoxks1GGsIIEX4xoCP_oQAvD_BwE)

Так же в лицензию включается:

> API и библиотеки, которые обеспечивают основу Qt. Qt содержит
>   богатый набор фундаментальных средств, которые обеспечивают компоненты
>   пользовательского интерфейса более высокого уровня и компоненты
>   разработки приложений.
>
> Дополнительные возможности Qt - невероятно всеобъемлющая структура,
>   полная возможностей, выходящих за рамки основ.
>
> инструменты Qt имеет собственную межплатформенную среду IDE и имеет
>   множество инструментов, предназначенных для разработки приложений и
>   пользовательских интерфейсов, и развертывания их в нескольких
>   операционных системах.
>
> Встроенные инструменты и решения У Qt есть готовые решения, которые
>   ускоряют создание вашего устройства с помощью функций качества
>   предприятия для действительно профессионального развития.
>
> Официальная служба поддержки поддержки Qt Группа поддержки экспертов
>   Qt помогает вам решать ваши задачи в области развития.
>
> Близкие стратегические отношения с компанией Qt

[Исходник(англ)](https://www.qt.io/download)

**Переведено с помощью google translate.**